# create a filter in django-datatables-view

Tags: python, django, datatable, datatables, django-datatable

I use django-datatables-view to render a huge dataset. 
I try to filter `'flat_price'`. It should be less or equal than a number that user writes in an input field

That's my DataTablesView:

```
class OrderListJson(BaseDatatableView):
    model = Flat
    columns = ['flat_house.adress', 'flat_price',]
    order_columns = ['flat_house.adress', 'flat_price',]
    max_display_length = 100

    def filter_queryset(self, qs):
        search = self.request.GET.get(u'search[value]', None)
        if search:
            qs = qs.filter(flat_price__lte=search)
```

I can't understand how filter_queryset works. When I try to load page with the datatable I've encountered with `AttributeError` : `'NoneType object has no attribute count'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter_queryset` should return `queryset`.

In your code, `filter_queryset(self, qs)` does not return any data.
so, `OrderListJson.get()` use `NoneType` as a queryset

```
def filter_queryset(self, qs):
    search = self.request.GET.get(u'search[value]', None)
    if search:
        qs = qs.filter(flat_price__lte=search)
    return qs
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to write a custom filter in `BaseDatatableView` for another <input> field in a html template?

Comment: @mailman_73 Did you figure out how to create a custom filter?

Answer (score 1):

You should return the filtered query

```
    def filter_queryset(self, qs):
        search = self.request.GET.get(u'search[value]', None)
        print(search)
        if search:
            qs = qs.filter(
                Q(field1__icontains=search) |
                Q(field2__icontains=search)
            )
        return qs
```

replace field1 and field2 with your modal's fields that you want them to be searchable.
**
Q is imported from
**

```
from django.db.models import Q
```